# How Do I Prevent Access To My Server via SSH During School Hours?

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, ssh, remote

I am doing homeschooling and I am wasting a lot of time on my server, how do I turn off SSH during school hours so it blocks me from accessing my server via ssh then when I am done it turns ssh back on? I have read about PAM_TIME but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start at it.

[This](https://www.tecmint.com/disable-or-enable-ssh-root-login-and-limit-ssh-access-in-linux/) shows one way to disable ssh by editing its configuration file and restarting it. To use it, you could construct two versions of /etc/ssh/sshd_config, one enabled and one disabled and write two cron scripts set to run on the server to switch between versions of the files at the appropriate times or replace the config file with a symlink that could be pointed at either version.

Just be sure you have physical access to the server or some other way to recover ssh access if something gets stuck or you have to get in for some reason during your restricted hours.

Even simpler, your cron jobs could just stop and start ssh at the appropriate times if it isn't being used in other ways during your restricted hours.

Note: I am not an experienced sysadmin, so I do not know if there are any security implications to this approach.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.